# Failing python 3.3 build in travis ci. Bug on the linux box/python installation?

Tags: argparse, python-3.3, travis-ci

I have a python 3.3 job failing on travis python 3.3 worker. Here is the link to the failing job:
https://travis-ci.org/rags/pynt/jobs/5482408

I believe this could be a problem with the worker for following reasons:

1. The build passes on my box (really!) with python 3.3
2. The travis build on 3.2 is passing
3. The error seems to be in the python 3.3 built-in library code. /usr/lib/python3.3/argparse.py:2028

Here are the relevant python 3.3 sources

- https://github.com/certik/python-3.3/blob/master/Lib/argparse.py
- https://github.com/certik/python-3.3/blob/master/Lib/gettext.py

There is a possibility that my code is doing something funny, but I cant seem to debug it.

Any pointers, suggestion will help

Thank you

Comment: Did you check the presence of ngettext? It throws NameError: global name 'ngettext' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**
This is a bug in travis. It has been accepted as one and a corresponding [ticket](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/998) has been raised. Hopefully, it will get fixed soon.